# Input a double range of values with start and end values

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, range

I have to select some values in a range, with a start and an end value, like in this image example :
[image]

I search with `<input type="range">` HTML element, but it can't have two selectors.

I can use **JavaScript** (even a library if a natural way doesn't exist) or **PHP**, and of course **HTML** and **CSS**. I didn't find anything like that, so you are my last hope.

Do you know something ?

P.S.: I know I could use two basics inputs, but it is a client wish to have a graphical unique input like that.

Comment: Try this http://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jquery double range slider for example http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/range.html

On http://plugins.jquery.com/ you can find lots of jquery plugins. If you look for range slider you will have more than one results.

Comment: Oh thank you for that ! But do you know of there is a way in pure JavaScript ? (just to be sure to not use a library for nothing.

Comment: jquery does it in javascript anyway. you could look in the source of jquery how they do it

Comment: Yes, you're right. I guess it is more easy, even if I'm not a big fan of external library. Thank you a lot for your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the jquery ui version does not work on mobile devices, and if you try to have jquery ui/jquery mobile working on the same page, they both have $.slider() methods, so they collide.

Answer (score 8):

### NO jQuery solution

If you are not working with jQuery (like us) you would love this solution:
https://refreshless.com/nouislider

Nice day

Answer (score 2):

jquery input range slider example:

http://designm.ag/tutorials/howto-build-range-slider-input-with-jqueryui/

Comment: Unfortunately the jquery ui version does not work on mobile devices, and if you try to have jquery ui/jquery mobile working on the same page, they both have $.slider() methods, so they collide.